# making containers use a different set a block devices

Tags: linux, container

Is it possible to make some Linux processes see a different set of block devices with containers (i.e. no virtualization such as KVM or Xen)? For example, at boot time the system recognizes `sda`, `sdb` and `sdc`, then `loop0` and `loop1` are created, and I want to start a process (running as root) which sees only `sdb` and `loop0`, but none of the others above. Please note that the other devices must remain hidden even if the process calls *mknod(2)* to create a block device node (which should succeed), and tries to open that (which should fail with `No such device`).

Please note that mounting a filesystem with the `nodev` flag doesn't work, because a process running as root can remount it without that flag.

Please note that running the process as non-root is not an option, because some complicated userspace components are running on the system which assume root access, and it would be too expensive to change those components. Reducing the capabilities of those processes is also not an option.

Most probably this is not possible, because http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/sched.h doesn't contain a `CLONE_NEW...` flag for block devices. But maybe I'm missing something.